# Build and deploy ASP app to Azure Web App fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am trying to create a deployment in Azure for an ASP.NET MVC 5 using .NET 4.8 (this is not a .net core application)

If I create the Web App from Visual Studio, code gets deployed.
But if I set up a deployment from GitHub:

[image: Asure Deployment Center]

The github action fails with the following error:

```
Run msbuild /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="\published\"
  SugarMonkey -> D:\a\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SugarMonkey\bin\SugarMonkey.dll
  SugarMonkey.Tests -> D:\a\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SugarMonkey.Tests\bin\Debug\SugarMonkey.Tests.dll
  Transformed Web.config using D:\a\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SugarMonkey\Web.Debug.config into obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
  Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
  \published\.
D:\a\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SC601PA-SugarMonkey\SugarMonkey.Tests\SugarMonkey.Tests.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder" does not exist in the project.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I resolve this error:

> The target "pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder" does not exist in the project.

Comment: I deleted the folder that was created for testing (SugarMonkey.Tests) and the action no longer fails

Comment: If it solved issue for you please post it as answer and accept it.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I am able to deploy, but I lost my testing capability, so that is more of a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this error by myself before but I did a research in our tools and found out that we have had a similar issue before. The problem was caused because the project was build as .Net Core application and after it was rebuilt as .Net Standard it was resolved. Is there a chance that you are referencing old dependencies?

Lastly, check out this article: [https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1109834/Error-MSB-The-target-Package-does-not-exist-in-t-2#:~:text=%20Error%20MSB4057:%20The%20target%20%22Package%22%20does%20not,for%20this%20entry%20is%20to%20help...%20More](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1109834/Error-MSB-The-target-Package-does-not-exist-in-t-2#:%7E:text=%20Error%20MSB4057:%20The%20target%20%22Package%22%20does%20not,for%20this%20entry%20is%20to%20help...%20More)

The article explains that the following code can be added in the .csproj to mitigate the issue:

```
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)
```

Let me know the outcome to these items.

Comment: Thank you that helped me moved along towards a solution,